# I have requirement with dates in powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have requirement with a specific date and days.

If Get-date = Today then it must check the weekends if Today date = weekend (saturday or sunday ) auto email should trigger on Friday itself with powershell.

Comment: Please, provide some details. Where the SharePoint in this scenario?

Comment: The actual thing is every 15 th and 30th I need to send auto email about time sheet submission.for example if 15 th is satday the email must be send on friday itself.

Comment: How would that work in February? :)

Comment: So your real question is `is  today the last workday before 1st or 16th day in month` ?

Comment: Yes like you said above @lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following switch statement would do.

```
switch ((Get-Date).DayOfWeek) 
{
    ([System.DayOfWeek]::Friday) {(Get-Date).Day -in (13,14,28,29)}
    default {(Get-Date).Day -in (15,30)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this with some functions

```
WorkingDay
LastDayInMonth
IsReportDay
```

They all accept a `-Date` parameter, if not supplied they use the current date as a default.

A small routine at begin demonstrates the use starting on june 12st and iterates 21 days from then on.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\29\SP_244303.ps1
$StartDate = Get-Date '2018-06-12'

for($i=0;$i -lt 21;$i++){
    $Date = (Get-Date -Date $StartDate).Date.AddDays($i)
    "{0,30:D} IsReportDay {1} " -f $Date,(IsReportDay $Date)
}

function IsReportDay {
  param ([datetime]$date=(Get-Date).Date)
  $IsReportDay = $False

  if (($date.Date -eq (WorkingDay (LastDayInMonth  $date).Date ) )  ){
    $IsReportDay = $True
  } ElseIf (($date.Date -eq (WorkingDay (Get-Date -Date $date -Day 15).Date ) )  ){
    $IsReportDay = $True
  }
  Return $IsReportDay
}

function LastDayInMonth {
    param ([datetime]$date=(Get-Date).Date)
    Return ((Get-Date -Date ($date.Date) -Day 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)).Date
}

function WorkingDay {
    param ([datetime]$date=(Get-Date).Date)

    While (!([int]$date.DayOfWeek % 6)){$date=$date.AddDays(-1)}
    Return $date.Date
}
```

Sample ouput:

```
> .\SP_244303.ps1
   Dienstag, 12. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
   Mittwoch, 13. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
 Donnerstag, 14. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
    Freitag, 15. Juni 2018 IsReportDay True
    Samstag, 16. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
    Sonntag, 17. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
     Montag, 18. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
   Dienstag, 19. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
   Mittwoch, 20. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
 Donnerstag, 21. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
    Freitag, 22. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
    Samstag, 23. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
    Sonntag, 24. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
     Montag, 25. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
   Dienstag, 26. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
   Mittwoch, 27. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
 Donnerstag, 28. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
    Freitag, 29. Juni 2018 IsReportDay True
    Samstag, 30. Juni 2018 IsReportDay False
     Sonntag, 1. Juli 2018 IsReportDay False
      Montag, 2. Juli 2018 IsReportDay False
```